# jQuery trigger does not trigger twice

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

```
app.helpers.Template.compileTemplate(tmplPath, tmplData).done(function(html) {
    view.$el.html(html);

    view.$('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
        console.log('focus')
    })

    view.$('input, select, textarea').trigger('focus');
});
```

Every time I create a view, I render the view's html and trigger a focus event on all of the form elements. The first view I create, everything is fine and I get "focus" in my console. The second time and all the times after, the callback is not being called...

Maybe it will help to know that it is always the same HTML that is being rendered, it's just different views.

Comment: I haven't looked too closely, but it looks to me like you're binding to DOM elements that get deleted / recreated when the view is rendered. So the `focus` handler that was created & bound when the template is compiled is not applied to the new DOM elements created when the view is rendered.

Comment: It is true that I'm binding to DOM elements that get deleted / recreated when the view is rendered, but why is it not applying the focus handler to the new elements?

Comment: It doesn't apply them because that's not how the `focus` method in jQuery works. See http://api.jquery.com/on/: "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: But the elements do exist when I do view.$('input, select, textarea').trigger('focus');. They are just newly created elements.

Comment: They exist until the template gets re-rendered then they are destroyed and re-created right? The event handlers are not carried over through that process.

Comment: Yes and each time the elements are recreated, I do $('input, select, textarea').trigger('focus');. So maybe i need to unbind and bind again?

Comment: I meant every time I do:     view.$('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
        console.log('focus')
    })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54742/discussion-between-ix3-and-maxwell).

Comment: Please consider posting a minimal example to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to a parent/ancestor element that does not get destroyed after you bind the handler then use a selector to identify the element on which you want to capture the focus event. Maybe something like (though you'll have to modify this to fit your layout -- didn't have any other information about your application on which to base this):

```
$("html").on("focusin", "input, select, textarea", function(e) { 
    /* your handler...might have to check e to see which element initiated the event */
});
```

Traditionally, this wasn't possible since `focus` events did not bubble, but jQuery tries to solve this problem:
http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

> The focus and blur events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser focusin and focusout events that do bubble. When focus and blur are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as focusin and focusout respectively. For consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names."

## UPDATE

Actually, if you are using backbone there is a designated way to do this: the `events` property of the view. See the "Listening for Events" section on [this page](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/).

> To attach a listener to our view, we use the "events" attribute of Backbone.View. Remember that event listeners can only be attached to child elements of the "el" property. Let us attach a "click" listener to our button.